# What is the best way to save/load contents of array to file?

Tags: arrays, macos, swift, file, save

I have a Swift application where I have an `NSTableView` populated by an array of custom structs, which contains an `NSSound` property. My question is, **what is the best way to save the content of this array to a file, and how would I load the array from said file?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the content to a file with:

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(rootObject: AnyObject, toFile: String)
```

Load the array with:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path: String)
```

Comment: I am just posting my opinion. No pressure please. Let me silently enjoy my first 10 points on stack overflow. :)

Comment: I guess I did not understand you, thinking that some advanced programmer is trying to pressure a newbie like me. Please do not be offended, 10 points is nothing vs. good explanation. To answer your question: For sure my method is debatable, I wrote this method because it first came to my mind.

Comment: This isn't working. When I try setting `rootObject` to my array, I get the error `Cannot invoke 'archiveRootObject' with an argument list of type '([Sound], toFile: String)'`.

Comment: does you Sound class conform to NSCoding protocol ?

Comment: Yes, it does now. That fixed it :)